# Thymeleaf : error while parsing user credentials inside registration form Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, registration

I need to complete the registration form on SpringBoot. To achieve this I created 2 classes : `User` and `Credentials`, the 2nd handles unique username and password.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    public User() {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    private String username;

}
```

---

```
public class Credentials {
    
    public static final String DEFAULT_ROLE = "DEFAULT";
    public static final String ADMIN_ROLE = "ADMIN";
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Getter
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    
    @Getter
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String role;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;

}
```

This is `registrationController` (handles `"/registration"` requests) :

```
@Controller
public class RegController {
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String register(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("credentials", new Credentials());
        return "register";
    }
}
```

Now it should be all set, ready to read data from html form and register new users using `thymeleaf`.
This is registration form inside `registration.html`, my goal is to read username and password then create a new user and save him on Postgres :

```
<body>
    <div class="login">
    <form id="login" method="POST" th:action="@{/register}">
        <label><b>User Name   
        </b>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="Uname" id="Uname" placeholder="Username" required th:field="${credentials.username}">    
        <br><br>    
        <label><b>Password     
        </b>    
        </label>    
        <input type="Password" name="Pass" id="Pass" placeholder="Password" required th:field="${credentials.password}">    
        <br><br>
        <label><b>Repeat Password     
        </b>    
        </label>    
        <input type="Password" name="RPass" id="RPass" placeholder="Password">    
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="log">Registrati</button>
        <div style = "background-color:green">
            <a id= "link" th:href="@{/login}" >or login</a>   
        </div>     
    </form>
</div>    
</body>
```

But when I navigate to registration.html this is the error from TomCat :

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: 
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/register.html]")
```

What I noticed is that if I remove all the `th:field` (used to get user input) the page is shown without error.

Comment: Is there a more detailed error message? Can you increase the log level in Spring. Put this in your `application.properties`: `logging.level.org.thymeleaf=TRACE` and
`logging.level.<namespace-to-controllers>=TRACE`

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC found also these 2 errors : org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: and : org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your Credentials class has only getters for `username` and `password`. If Thymeleaf has to fill them with the user input, shouldn't you provide setters too?

```java
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
```

Comment: What do you mean ? I thought that add "@Getter" and "@Setter" before would automatically generates getter and setter for both username and password

Comment: Yes, but in your code snippet you provided only `@Getter` for both but no `@Setter`. Maybe you overlooked that?